# rpc/encoding with JAXWS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, axis

**Premise of my environment:** I'm running on Spring 3 using spring-ws to process all SOAP requirements. I've done multiple integrations with various vendors without issues on this.

**Problem:** This recent integration has a vendor running really archaic stuff and their WSDLs are using rpc bind styles. Needless to say JAXWS doesn't quite support rpc (and rightly so since its the antithesis of interop).

**Possible solution #1:** I can still attempt to generate the stubs on their WSDL using Axis 1. In fact I've already done this but am very very reluctant to introduce the Axis dependency into my pom. I'm pretty sure there will be a massive amount of library conflicts that might potentially mess up what's a very stable environment currently.

**Possible solution #2:** I can try to rewrite their WSDL into document/literals that JAXWS will be able to parse. Running into some issues actually rewriting the WSDLs (Getting "Schema descriptor {xxx}xxx in message part "xxx" is not defined and could not be bound to Java"). Besides if their endpoints check specifically for rpc I'm screwed anyways.

**Possible solution #3:** I can deploy a completely new box running Axis and this service client specifically. Ie main project makes REST call to this box which makes the SOAP request and parses the response back. Seems like a very very silly way (and a ridiculous amount of work for something that should be simple) to go about doing it tho.

Any solutions I've missed ? Also I've been trawling google for this and while some people have successes with #1, nobody really talks about the fallout after. (i.e. dealing with Axis's legacy dependencies, trying to make Axis play nice in Spring 3, etc)

Answer (score 0):

**#1**

One way to make #1 more stable is to get yourself a local copy of the Axis sources that you will use to build your own copy of the Axis jar(s). But you change the packaging of the whole thing. Instead of org.apache.axis, for example, it becomes com.mycompany.org.apache.axis and the translation becomes pretty mechanical.

Then, any dependencies of Axis1 (like an old version of commons-beanutils, maybe) would get the same treatment. Load their jars. Build their jar(s) with your own custom packaging. (If they build with Maven, determining dependencies is somewhat easier.)

Doing this does sacrifice some effort in the ability to incorporate updates and fixes to the original Axis code. Any released update becomes a set of changes you have to figure out how to incorporate into your local copy in which every .java file has changes to the `package` and `imports` lines.

**#2**

Dunno about #2. Its a roll of the dice, isn't it.

**#3**

What you are doing in #3 is what an ESB is really good at. Number 3 is where you write your own mini-translator. I've done that and it works just fine.

But you can actually build step 3 on the same box. You don't need another box. You deploy the little translator app as a separate application running on the main port. You deploy your application on a different port or as a different URL/path. The translator app uses Axis1 and translates the incoming message, passes it on and translates the response back.

One nice thing about this solution is that it handles the load balancing as if you had one application. The load goes up on the translator app and the main app together using up their shared bucket of cpu cycles. If you need more, add more servers set up exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Lee.
#1 Not sure what you mean precisely. The stubs that are generated via Axis' WSDL2Java inherently extends Axis specific objects. For instance, all services inherits from org.apache.axis.client.Service. Are you suggesting I include all Axis sources in my source base and refactor them as opposed to including Axis as a maven dependency ?

Comment: #3 Yeah I hear you, a bad terminology on my part. I didn't mean box as in a physical box but a separate logical context and a different deployed application. Can very well sit on the same boxes altho that's a different can of worms since I'm clustered with many many boxes. ESB sounds like a huge overkill !

Comment: Yes, I do mean building your own Axis jar from your own, slightly modified as to packages, copy of Axis source. Don't really mix it totally in with your own source. I've seen this done to good effect in stuff like Weblogic or WebSphere where they want to use 3rd party jars but don't want their version to conflict with the versions required by their customers. New Websphere uses OSGI to avoid the problem a different way.